# Python - Log line numbers with bad data in csv [error_bad_lines,warn_bad_lines]

Tags: pandas, python-3.6

Basically, I'm trying to parse csv file in Pandas with bad lines and added following parameters.

```
error_bad_lines=False,warn_bad_lines=True
```

Also, I'm redirecting output of warning message with following code snippet -

```
from contextlib import redirect_stderr
import io
   
f = io.StringIO()
with redirect_stderr(f):
    df = pd.read_csv(fname,sep=',',error_bad_lines=False,warn_bad_lines=True)

if f.getvalue():
    msg = f.getvalue()
```

Now, issue is - above code redirects byte like output to string which looks like -

```
"b'Skipping line 4: expected 85 fields, saw 86\\nSkipping line 6: expected 85 fields, saw 101\\n'\n"
```

I'm trying to write warning message as individual lines in log with string repalce/split and then iterating over list with custom write_log method.

```
msg_list = msg.replace('b\'','').replace('\'','').split('\\n')

print (msg_list)
```

output looks like -
['Skipping line 4: expected 85 fields, saw 86', 'Skipping line 6: expected 85 fields, saw 101', '\n']

Is there an efficient way to write individual entry in log ?
Expected Output is

```
 ['Skipping line 4: expected 85 fields, saw 86', 'Skipping line 6: expected 85 fields, saw 101']
```

EDIT: Ultimate goal is just to get the line numbers which have bad data. i.e. [4.6]

python: 3.6.4
pandas: 1.1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple regex solution worked -

```
import re
regex = re.compile('line ([0-9]*)')
print (regex.findall(warning_str))
```